# Make entire card clickable by targeting <a> inside of it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some cards with an image, text, and link within them. Wrapping the card with an anchor tag is not possible in my case. Is it possible to target the anchor tag within the card and then make the entire card clickable to go to that link using jquery?

**Ideal state**: when you click anywhere on the card, the link is triggered and the user is taken to it.

```
<div class="todays-news">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="images/home/home-image.png" />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <strong>This is a title</strong>
                    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
                    <a href="https://www.example.com/">Continue Reading</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="images/home/home-image-2.png" />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <strong>This is a title</strong>
                    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
                    <a href="https://www.example.com/">Continue Reading</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm curious why it's not possible to make the entire card an anchor...?

Comment: If you want to click anywhere on the card, make the whole card the link, ie `<a class="card">...</a>`. Don't do this with JavaScript, it breaks the user's browser and the fundamental contracts of the Internet in so many ways: Users can't preview the link to see where it leads, they can't navigate to the link or click it with the keyboard or assistive devices, they can't right-click/middle click to open in a new tab, etc etc. It's a terrible practice.

Answer (score 11):

This can be achieved with css, no javascript required.

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
}

.item a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

The element that you want to make clickable gets a `position: relative`. That creates a new containment block. We then add a `before` pseudo-class to the link. Position it absolutely and stretch it over the entire containment block.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/q0Pje5H2Br

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with JavaScript, though if you could solve the problem with not being able to make the card an anchor, that would be better. There's no reason you can't put a `div` in an [`a` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), `a`'s content model is [transparent](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#transparent).

But if you can't:

```
$(document).on("click", ".card", function(event) {
    const $this = $(this);
    // Don't interfere with a click actually on the anchor
    // (that way, the user can still right-click it and
    // use the browser-supplied menu for oew in new tab,
    // shift click, etc.)
    if ($this.find($(event.target).closest("a")[0]).length === 0) {
        // Not on the anchor, do it
        event.preventDefault();
        $this.find("a")[0].click();
    }
});
```

Note that you have to call `click` on the DOM element, not the jQuery object. If you call it on the jQuery object, it won't trigger the default action.

Comment: @rocket129083 - Not really, I would keep the code that doesn't interfere with it in case you change your styling/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click handler for the card, and have it perform a click on the anchor:

```
$(".card").click(function() {
  $(this).find("a")[0].click();
});
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter, since the user doesn't need to click on the link.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure that's true (the documentation of `.trigger()` says you have to use `.triggerHandler()` to not trigger the native actions), but I've changed the code to call it on the DOM element.

Comment: @Barmar - I tested it before posting the comment. (I, too, had just written `.find("a").click()` and then was reminded of the issue when it didn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an `onclick` handler on the `div`:

```html
<div class="todays-news">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="card" onclick="this.querySelector('a').click(); return true;">
                  <img src="images/home/home-image.png" />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <strong>This is a title</strong>
                    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
                    <a href="https://www.example.com/">Continue Reading</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" onclick="this.querySelector('a').click(); return true;">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="images/home/home-image-2.png" />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <strong>This is a title</strong>
                    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
                    <a href="https://www.example.org/">Continue Reading</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The link will not be shown to the user, it will be "display:none" using css. Not sure if that makes a difference to this answer...thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap block elements with `<a>`. It is valid HTML5 and renders your card clickable. You may need to adjust the css rules for the text inside this block however.

Edit: Since this isn't possible in your case, could you specify why?

```
<div class="todays-news">
<div class="container">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <a class="item" href="https://www.example.com/">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="images/home/home-image.png" />
              <div class="card-body">
                <strong>This is a title</strong>
                <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
                <a>Continue Reading</a>  <!-- unsure about the correct tag here -->
              </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="item" href="https://www.example.com/">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="images/home/home-image-2.png" />
              <div class="card-body">
                <strong>This is a title</strong>
                <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
                <a>Continue Reading</a> <!-- unsure about the correct tag here -->
              </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can. But the OP said it's *"...not possible in [their] case."* It's not great to post an answer that just ignores part of the question.

Comment: Ah! Sorry I should have read more carefully